# How to do a better and easier roll transition in Kdenlive

Tags: transitions, kdenlive

I've been using Kdenlive for a month or so. One of my favorite transitions is a roll transition, where the old clip slides out (e.g. from the center to the left) while at the same time the new clip slides in (e.g. from the right to the center) creating the effect of the old clip being pushed out by the new clip. To do this in Kdenlive, I slightly overlap the two clips in different tracks then apply two Slide transform, one to the old clip (a slide out) and one to the new clip (a slide in).

However:

1. this is time consuming;
2. the movement is linear, there isn't a way to a dynamism or speed changes in the movement.

Any ideas on how to do a better and easier roll transition in Kdenlive?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try the other transitions again
Please do not be absolutist
I also enjoy the transition roll
But
Do a quick Google search for smooth transitions. Maybe it's right for you
Good luck